# validation using DB query in Clustered enviornment

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a validation which checks in DB for uniqueness. My question is "If my application is deployed in clustered environment then how to can i do this? " My current implementation is simply firing the DB query to check if value exist in any of the records. But if i have to deploy my application in clustered environment i suppose this implementation will not work simply as there could be two different request from two different user/server while one of them is still committing changes in DB which second request cannot see yet. Hope i am able to make it clear ...

Comment: You might already have an issue even with a single server : usually a server have more than one treatment thread. What is triggering the insertion ? is it a user triggered transaction, or is it a transaction started by a batch job ? What should happen to thread 2 if it violates the unique constraint : use the row created by thread 1 or totally abort treatment ?

Comment: "check if value exist in any of the records" -- you shouldn't care about this usually, as long as there's DB-level uniqueness constraint on values' column, like primary key or unique index. You'll get `SQLException` if this is violated, and uniqueness still holds.

Comment: We cannot assign unique constraint as this is an order management application where there can be multiple orders for the same user with same value. Although only one order(Max) is active at a time status = "In service".